# How do I run react-scripts with chrome on windows 11

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

react-scripts start opens firefox (which is my default browser), I've tried to following to make it open chrome on start.

1. set BROWSER=chrome in `.env` file (also tried google-chrome and google-chrome-stable)
2. set in package.json     `"start": "BROWSER=chrome react-scripts start"`
3. installing cross-env and adding `cross-env BROWSER=chrome` in package.json

Neither works.

Comment: Might be a silly question but do you actually have regular Google Chrome installed (not canary)? You could always try passing the full path to the Chrome executable as detailed [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open#app) in your `.env` file